# Stop function giving new results when page refreshes django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a function that takes inputted choices and gives random objects from the database that match the users choice:

```
def someFunction():
 if choice == 'Choice1'
  result = Choice1.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]
 elif choice == 'Choice2'
  result = Choice2.objects.all.order_by('?')[0]
 return result
```

It is passed to the view like so:

```
def ChoiceView():
context = {
    'Choice': someFunction(),
}
return render(request, 'project/choice.html', context)
```

The issue I'm having is that because the function gives random objects by design every time the page is refreshed a different qualifying result is given.

I want to keep the function random, however once the function is ran, I don't want it to be ran again when the page is refreshed but rather keep the original function results to remain until the choice parameters change, or it is purposely refreshed with the intention of getting a new set of results, or a given time period has elapsed etc

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep some piece of data like that the same between page refreshes, you would need to store it somewhere. There are various ways to do this, but some options are:

1) Store it in the database. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but essentially storing this field in a Model, associated with a user, and retrieving it each time.

2) Store it in the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/).  Easy to get started with because you can store things in the session with `request.session`. Not as permanent as the database option, but will persist between page loads.

Comment: Thanks for the response...the session seems like a good solution as I only need the results available for around 24 hours.